# MySQL-server-5.5.18 - Installation issues / doubts

Tags: mysql5.5

1 ) How to relocate the data dir while installing the MySQL-server-5.5.18-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm.

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.5.18-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the second question?

Answer (score 0):

If a my.cnf is present when MySQL is installed, it will override any default settings with the values specified there.  So you can simply create your /etc/my.cnf with the following content:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/my/specified/datadir
```